# jQuery .click() event not working as expected with mobile browsers. How do I fix it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently working on a project (ASP.NET MVC) where I need a user's choice from a dropdown menu to hide/show divs on selection. The following code is working great in desktop browsers. I, however, am running into a bug on Android and iOS browsers.

In order for my code to work properly on mobile browsers, I need to select and then re-select an option from this dropdown menu. In other words, when I first select an option from the dropdown menu, none of the expected divs are hiding/showing. When I go back into the dropdown and re-select the same option, the divs then hide/show. I want my code to work on one selection.

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-12 required" id="petChoiceType">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PetChoice, new { @class = "control-label" })
      @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PetChoice, petType.Select(d => new SelectListItem { Value = d.Key, Text = d.Value }).ToList(), "-- Please Select --  ", new { @class = "form-control", required = "required", id = "petOptions" })
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PetChoice, "Please select", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('#petChoiceType').click(function () {
    if ($('#petOptions').val() === "Dog") {
        $('.individualInformationSection').toggle();
    }

    if ($('#petOptions').val() === "Cat") {
        $('#coBuyerInfo').toggle();
        $('#coBuyerSignatureSection').toggle();
    }

    if ($('#petOptions').val() === "Bird") {
        $('#coBuyerInfo').toggle();
        $('#coBuyerSignatureSection').toggle();
        $('#buyerSignatureTitleSection').toggle();
        $('#SSN').removeAttr('required');
        $('#buyerInfoSection').toggleClass('required');       
    }

    else {
        $('#SSN').attr('required');
    }
});
```

CSS (this was a suggested fix here on SO, although it doesn't seem to have any effect)

```
html {
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

I have tried changing the .click() to `.select()` and to `.change()`.

`.select()`: the code continued to work correctly on desktop browsers but the dropdown menu lost all functionality in the mobile browsers

`.change()`: I was unable to select a different option from the menu and trigger the divs hiding/showing. The app was stuck on the user's first choice. I really need this functionality.

I have yet to try anything with jQuery Mobile. I have never used it before, so I wouldn't even know where to begin to start troubleshooting.

I was working on the following addition to my jQuery code, but I realize that I need to replace that `.click()` event with something else. If all I need to do is just find a replacement for the `.click()` event, I suppose this code wouldn't be necessary:

jQuery

```
if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    $('#petChoiceType').click(function () {
        if ($('#petOptions').val() === "Dog") {
            $('.individualInformationSection').toggle();
        }

        if ($('#petOptions').val() === "Cat") {
            $('#coBuyerInfo').toggle();
            $('#coBuyerSignatureSection').toggle();
        }

        if ($('#petOptions').val() === "Bird") {
            $('#coBuyerInfo').toggle();
            $('#coBuyerSignatureSection').toggle();
            $('#buyerSignatureTitleSection').toggle();
            $('#SSN').removeAttr('required');
            $('#buyerInfoSection').toggleClass('required');       
        }

        else {
            $('#SSN').attr('required');
        }
     });
 }
```

This is the only bug I am running into with my jQuery code on mobile browsers. I'm struggling to even understand what's going on, so this has been such a pain to troubleshoot. If someone could explain to me what's going on and show me how to get around this bug, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Instead of firing your functionality on click of the element, you should be firing it on change of the select box. `cursor:pointer` is just a stylistic change, it doesn't change functionality, it just changes the cursor icon to indicate something is clickable. I see that you said you tried `.change()` but unless you changed the target, it wouldn't work as you have it, the `.change()` needs to be associated with the select box itself, not the parent container.

Comment: `$('#petOptions').change(function() { });` is what you would need to use.

Comment: I tried changing .click() to .change() and I lost the form's ability to modify based on dropdown menu's choice. So, for example, if the user chooses "dog", the dog version of the form appears. If this was an accident and the user really meant to choose "cat", the user clicks "cat" but the dog version of the form is still on the page. I need this functionality. My front-end validation is dependent on it.

Comment: Simply changing `.click()` to `.change()` will not help you. `.change()` needs to be associated with the select box, currently you're targeting the parent of the select box, `#petChoiceType`, see my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the rest of your code, I can't give you an exact answer, but it should look more like this:

```js
$('#petOptions').change(function () {
    var petVal = $(this).val();
    
    // This will show you the value that's being returned by your select element
    console.log(petVal);
    
    if (petVal === "Dog") {
        $('.individualInformationSection').toggle();
    } else if (petVal === "Cat") {
        $('#coBuyerInfo').toggle();
        $('#coBuyerSignatureSection').toggle();
    } else if (petVal === "Bird") {
        $('#coBuyerInfo').toggle();
        $('#coBuyerSignatureSection').toggle();
        $('#buyerSignatureTitleSection').toggle();
        $('#SSN').removeAttr('required');
        $('#buyerInfoSection').toggleClass('required');       
    } else {
        $('#SSN').attr('required');
    }
});
```

Here's a working sample using the code:

```js
$('#petOptions').change(function () {
    var petVal = $(this).val();
    
    // This will show you the value that's being returned by your select element
    console.log(petVal);
    
    if (petVal === "Dog") {
        alert('You chose dog');
    } else if (petVal === "Cat") {
        alert('You chose cat');
    } else if (petVal === "Bird") {
        alert('You chose bird');       
    } else {
        alert('You chose nothing');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="petOptions">
  <option disabled selected>--Choose an animal--</option>
  <option value="Dog">Dog</option>
  <option value="Cat">Cat</option>
  <option value="Bird">Bird</option>
  <option>Nothing</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Still not working for me. I tried switching all of the code inside the if-else statements to alerts and I'm still not experiencing the switching I need to happen. When I try to switch from one option to the other, the "else" alert keeps popping up.

Comment: Sounds like your `select` value is not matching any of the conditions then. `console.log` out the value and make sure you're actually getting what you're expecting.